# How do I call a servlet from a JSP page to perform an automatic redirect?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a JSP page to another page -- the catch is that I don't necessarily know the URL that I'm redirecting to. So my thought was that when the JSP loads, it calls a servlet that figures out the new URL and performs the redirect. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this, and I don't think I've come across someone who's asked this question already. Help? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What have you started with? Please post some code and tell us how far you've gotten, what your ideas are to solving this problem, an what you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forward()` (assuming it's the same server):

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/service-that-redirects");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

If the url-resolver service is on another server, use `sendRedirect()`:

```
response.sendRedirect("http://otherserver.com/redirect-service?param1=a&param2=b&...");
```

If you want to learn more about the difference between these two options: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/sendredirect-forward-jsp-servlet.html

Comment: sendRedirect worked! Thank you!